# sass --watch doesn't watch on FreeBSD

Tags: sass, freebsd, watch

I have Sass running on FreeBSD system (managed to make [the linux package](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases) work using `linux_base-c7` emulator and `kldload linux64`).

If I run it manually like

```
sass style.scss style.css
```

It works fine.

But somewhy it doesn't enter the watch mode. When I type

```
sass --watch style.scss style.css
```

It doesn't print any message ("Sass is watching..." or something like that). And the watch doesn't work either: `style.css` remains unchaged when I modify and save `style.scss`.

What may be wrong with it and where can I look for errors?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but try `node-sass` too

Comment: @ııı, it requires Node.js which I don't use.

Comment: Ok but maybe it works (and doesn't require ¬inux emulation)

Answer (score 1):

The issue apparently comes from running it on FreeBSD system: it's `watch` utility is completely different from Linux's `watch`, so `--watch` option doesn't work.

The workaround may be achieved using `inotify-tools` package (required installation).

I wrote a script, let's name it `sass-watch.sh`, which allows to establish watch over the given directory, like:

```
sh sass-watch.sh .
```

Here is what inside of this script:

```sh
nohup \
inotifywait \
  --recursive \
  --monitor  \
  --event close_write \
  --include '\.scss$' \
  $1 \
| while read arg; do \
    sass $1:$1 ; \
  done &
```

The script will run in background an remain even after you log out from the shell.

Comment: `cmdwatch` https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cmdwatch, to keep up and running something forever you could try `immortal` https://immortal.run/freebsd/

Comment: Alternatively, you may check out [entr](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/entr/).

Comment: @nbari, thanks for the suggestions, `immortal` could fit.

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski, very interesting. I've heard about such tools before but never in details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What version of `sass` are you using? From looking at the code, it looks like it uses `sass-listen` which uses `kqueue` on FreeBSD:

https://rubygems.org/gems/sass/versions/3.7.4

https://rubygems.org/gems/sass-listen/versions/4.0.0

https://github.com/sass/listen/blob/v4.0.0/lib/sass-listen/adapter/bsd.rb

So it shouldn't be calling `watch(1)` at all.

Comment: `sass --version` yelds `1.17.2`. When trying to call `kqueue` from the command line it says the command is not found.

Comment: I can't seem to find a version of sass like that: https://rubygems.org/gems/sass/versions so how was this installed? If it's from a package/port, can you run `pkg which \`which sass\`` and tell me what it shows?

Comment: It's dart-sass, downloaded from https://github.com/sass/dart-sass several weeks ago (pretty fresh).
I probably created misambiguation on version number. Should I edit the question and mention that I'm using Dart Sass?

Comment: As far as I knew, dart doesn't support FreeBSD at all, so I'm even more confused now.

Comment: I downloaded it straight from [official Github repository](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases). It works fine for me, except the `--watch` option.